# How to get the band level of an audio file in Android.Equalizer

Tags: android, audio, equalizer

I have an `AudioTrack` generated in my code. I retrieved the code from [here](http://marblemice.blogspot.com/2010/04/generate-and-play-tone-in-android.html).

What i need to do is to get the band level of the tone generated. So, to be able to do this, I initialized an `Equalizer`, and set the audio session to the session id of the generated audio track.

```
audioTrackSessionId = audioTrack.getAudioSessionId();
equalizer = new Equalizer(1, audioTrackSessionId);
equalizer.setEnabled(true);
```

What I need is to retrieve the band level for the frequency given, let's say `freqOfTone = 1000; //Hz` so I need to get the level of band 2 (band 2 's range is 461Hz to 1800Hz).

If I use `equalizer.getBandLevel(2)` it's returning the level of the equalizer by default, not the level of the generated tone (audioTrack).

Does anyone know how to retrieve the band level of the generated tone?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not supported by the Equalizer API. You could try using the [Visualizer.getFft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#getFft(byte[])) method instead.

Comment: But how can i get the level in db for a frequency given using getFft() method?

Comment: @Hanady have you checked the answer.Why don't you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

getBandLevel like this

```
short minEQLevel = equalizerWrapper.getBandLevelRange()[0];

short maxEQLevel = equalizerWrapper.getBandLevelRange()[1];
```